# How to store a structure pointer in C so data is not loss?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, structure

I have this code

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
  char   brand[40];
  int    year;
  int    km;
  float  price;
}Autos;

int userInput;
void menu();
void scanCars(Autos *pointer);
void print_struct(Autos *pointer);


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  Autos *pointerCar, Cars;
  pointerCar=&Cars;
  pointerCar=(Autos  *)malloc(5*sizeof(Autos));
  int value= 1;
    while (value)
    {
    menu();
      switch (userInput)
      {
        case 1:
         scanCars(pointerCar);

          break;
        case 2:
          print_struct(pointerCar);

          break;
        case 3:
          value=0;
          break;
      }

    }
  free(pointerCar);
  return 0;
}
void menu()
{
    printf("1) Input Cars:\n" );
    printf("2) Print Cars:\n" );
    printf("3) Exit\n" );
    scanf("%d", &userInput );
    printf("=================\n" );
}
void scanCars(Autos *pointer)
{
  printf("1) Scanning CARS:\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
  {
    printf("Brand:");
    scanf("%s", (pointer+i)->brand);

    printf("Year: ");
    scanf("%d", &(pointer+i)->year );

    printf("Kilometros:");
    scanf("%d",&(pointer+i)->km );

    printf("price: ");
    scanf("%f",&(pointer+i)->price );
  }
    printf("=================\n" );

}
void print_struct(Autos *pointer)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    printf("Car #[%d]\n",i+1 );
    printf("Brand: %s\n",(pointer+i)->brand);
    printf("Year: %d\n",(pointer+i)->year );
    printf("Kilometraje: %d\n",(pointer+i)->km );
    printf("Price: $%.2f\n",(pointer+i)->price );
    printf("=================\n" );
  }

}
```

The code runs fine to store some cars data and then print it when ask for it.

## Problem:

When I try for second time to store new cars Data I lost my last input. So my question is how can I store a new structure array and print the whole data:

## Example:

1. each `*pointerCar` has 5 CARS
2. So how to save `*pointerCar to array[3] of pointerCars`
3. I will have in total 15 cars in TOTAL, but each AUTOS will have 5 CARS

My problem is that every time I run the code the data I wrote from the last cars its rewritten.
[image: Image for Input Cars]
[image: Image for Printing Cars]
[image]

Comment: First you point `pointerCar` to  `Cars`, but then you immediately assign it to the results of `malloc`.

Comment: If you want to store more than one car you have to store them in different places.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons, YES so I can Have 5 cars for each pointerCar

Comment: That explains why you assign `pointerCar` the results of `malloc`, but `Cars` never comes into play.  You create it, point something to it, and then point that thing away from it never to touch it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, a few things to avoid to make the code more readable, and easier to debug:

`Autos *pointerCar, Cars;` - don't do that, it aggravates readability. I assume you wanted to declare a two pointers: `pointerCar` - for a single car, and `cars` for an array of cars. In your code you've declare a pointer `pointerCar` and **variable** `Cars`.

Establish one naming convention and stick to it. If you use a CamelCase for types, don't use it for variables (use camelCase or snake_case instead). Don't use plural for types. I would write it like that:

```
Auto *single_car;
Auto *cars;
```

Use `calloc` for structure and array initialization, because it fills the allocated memory with zeros, which is convenient.

```
cars = (Auto*) calloc(5, sizeof(Auto));
```

### And now the issue

You lose your last input, because every time you call the `scanCars` function, you pass the same pointer again and again. Your `*pointerCar` points to an array of 5 Auto's, then you fill it with data in `scanCars` and return from function. The next time the `scanCars` is called, it has the same pointer passed as an argument and overwrites the data.

> I will have in total 15 cars in TOTAL, but each AUTOS will have 5 CARS;

Something's wrong here. You only have one type defined: `Autos` (which should be just `Auto`). If you allocate a space for 5 Autos, you'll get a pointer to a memory prepared for storing 5 Auto structures and nothing more.

If you want to group your Autos to some form of hypothetical garage, you have to create a table of pointers to Auto (or simply saying: a table of tables of Autos). For example:

```
Auto *garage[3];
garage[0] = (Auto*) calloc(5, sizeof(Auto));
garage[1] = (Auto*) calloc(5, sizeof(Auto));
garage[2] = (Auto*) calloc(5, sizeof(Auto));
```

And now each element of `garage` contains an array of 5 Autos. To access a car in a garage, you'll write: `garage[1][0].year`.

Now you can pass a garage to you `scanCars` function: `scanCars(garage[0])`. Remember to adjust the for-loop in `scanCars`, because it is set to fill only 2 cars and now should have 5.

Answer (score -1):

If you have 5 Cars, declare the array of cars:
`Auto Cars[5];` Then you point pointerCar to each of the Cars 0 thru 4 in sequence.

Answer (score -1):

This problem can easily be solved by using array of pointers.

```
Autos *pointerCar;
```

This pointer can be used to store address of one structure of type Autos. You can take array like this.

```
Autos *pointerCar[number_of_cars];
```

For the ith car allocate the ith pointer through malloc as

```
pointerCar[i]=(Autos  *)malloc(sizeof(Autos));
```

If you do not have knowledge of array of pointers then refer to [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pointer-array-array-pointer/).